# I'm trying to switch gravity in Unity 5 and my code won't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. No error message is being shown, the code just won't work. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gravityswitch : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool ChangeGravity;

    void Start () {
        ChangeGravity = false;
    }

    void Update (){

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.I) && ChangeGravity == false) {
            ChangeGravity = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.K) && ChangeGravity == true) {
            ChangeGravity = false;
        }

        if (ChangeGravity == true) {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3 (5f, -9.81f, 0f);
        } 
        else if (ChangeGravity == false) {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3 (-5f, 9.81f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, classes name starts in capital letter and camel case to follow and variable name starts in not capital letter and then camel case (as a standard). 
Passing to the problem.. did you try to just make it run on the Start and not in the Update? Because with that code you are calling the physics api every frame. In the end make sure that the script is attached to a gameobject.